# Multiple servers in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to run concurrent Jupyter Lab sessions, where the sessions are served by different servers (for example, a *local* machine and a *remote* (cloud) server, or two cloud servers).

If a Jupyter Lab instance is running on my local machine and I type `jupyter lab` on a remote machine and paste the URL in my browser, it asks for a new workspace name or sometimes offers a localhost address that ends in :8889 instead of :8888, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add the remotely-hosted notebook to the existing Jupyter Lab instance as a new tab in Jupyter lab, or to run it side-by-side as a new browser tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to get two cloud VMs running side-by-side Jupyter Lab sessions in the tabs of one browser.

I had configured SSH so that my cloud VM was forwarded to port 8888.  The answer was to add a second SSH configuration for the second VM so that it forwarded to port 8889, and then make matching entries in the `jupyter_notebook_config` files on the two machines, like this:

1. Edit .ssh/config on your local machine (replace the contents of <...> and the identity file to adapt this to your situation)

```
##Override for Azure machine 1 ##
Host <IP address of VM 1>
   User <your username on VM1>
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vm1_rsa #SSH private key
   LocalForward 8888 localhost:8888

##Override for Azure machine 2 ##
Host <IP address of VM 2>
   User <your username on VM2>
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/vm2_rsa #SSH private key (could be the same as for VM1)
   LocalForward 8889 localhost:8889
```

2. Edit the `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` file on each machine so that VM1's file includes the line `c.NotebookApp.port = 8888` and VM2's file includes the line  `c.NotebookApp.port = 8889`.

I haven't tested it yet for the case where you want to run side-by-side Jupyter Lab sessions from a local machine and a remote machine, but I assume the mechanics would be the same.